# java substring by Regex

Tags: java, regex, substring

I have following string "Class (102) (401)" and "Class (401)" i want to find regex to find substring which always return me value 'Class' out of "Class (102) (401)" or "Class (102)"

Following is my code

```
Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".^(\\(\\d+\\))");
    Matcher mat = MY_PATTERN.matcher("Class (102) (401)");
    while (mat.find()){
        System.out.println(mat.group());
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you do something simple and obvious like `^\S+`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how that might be useful - but if you need it, the 'class' will be in the first matching group if you use this regex:

```
(Class)(?:\s*\(\d+\))+
```

If you need to capture other words followed by the same pattern just use:

```
(.*?)(?:\s*\(\d+\))+
```

If it's the numbers that you are after rather than the string 'class' use this one and the matches will be also in the capturing groups:

```
Class(?:\s*\(\(d+)\))+
```

You'll need to escape the backslashes, I left that out for readability.

Comment: If OP needs numbers, then his own regex is already perfect, except for those `.^` at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use String.contains("Class") if you want to know if 'Class' is contained in a String?

Comment: Class is only an example string there will be another value instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String#replaceAll to get what you want like this:

```
String substr = str.replaceAll("^([\\S]+).*$", "$1");
```